# Android studio beginner :( Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle

1. Hi, Im new to coding and android studio. I wrote just a simple PSVM SOUT message and the code is correct but this is what it shows in my terminal (BTW this is a fresh new install) :

   ```
   Initialization script 'C:\Users\Dom\AppData\Local\Temp\MainActivity_main__.gradle' line: 20

   * What went wrong:
   A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
   > Could not create task ':app:MainActivity.main()'.
   > SourceSet with name 'main' not found.

   * Try:
   Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more 
   log 
   output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

   *     Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

   Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
   Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
   See https://docs.gradle.org/5.4.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
   ```

   The gradle file that it is referring to looks like this:

```
    def gradlePath = ':app'
    def runAppTaskName = 'MainActivity.main()'
    def mainClass = 'com.example.myapplication.MainActivity'
    def javaExePath = 'S:/Program files (x86)/androidStudio/jre/bin/java.exe'
    def _workingDir = 'C:/Users/Dom/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication'

    def sourceSetName = 'main'
    def javaModuleName = null





    allprojects {
      afterEvaluate { project ->
        if(project.path == gradlePath && project?.convention?.findPlugin(JavaPluginConvention)) {
          project.tasks.create(name: runAppTaskName, overwrite: true, type: JavaExec) {
            if (javaExePath) executable = javaExePath
            classpath = project.sourceSets[sourceSetName].runtimeClasspath
            main = mainClass

            if(_workingDir) workingDir = _workingDir
            standardInput = System.in
            if(javaModuleName) {
              inputs.property('moduleName', javaModuleName)
              doFirst {
                jvmArgs += [
                  '--module-path', classpath.asPath,
                  '--module', javaModuleName + '/' + mainClass
                ]
                classpath = files()
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

I have tried to update the gradle version but when I updated it to 6 it said it wasn't compatible with gradle 7. It says to run with --stacktrace option but what is it referring to? 
where do I run this line of code?

Answer (score 0):

You telling gradle to use the sourceset main which is normaly default, but do you really have a folder called main ?

I would expect you have this kind of folder ?

```
C:/Users/Dom/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/src/main
```

Which version of Java do you use ?

Comment: I use JSE 8 and the directory is C:\Users\Dom\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\src\main  and has a java folder, res folder , and anndroidManifest document. How could I set sourcet to default?

Comment: Do you have a multi gradle project, because if not then your allprojects configuration is a bit overkill. Normally if you only have one module then you don't need to define the all projects configuration scope. https://developer.android.com/studio/build skip to the section with the gradle build file